# Why mongoDb atlas not working on a server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a rest api in nodejs with express and mongoDb (mongoose).
In localhost everything works nice, now i want to deploy it.

I use O2switch (host) who use Cpanel, i configure everything and if i do a request it's works, but the response is a error because my script fail on :

```
const user = await User.findOne({ email })
```

> The findOne not work because mongoDb fail at some point.

The error logs who seems to crash the server:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

I try before to whitelist the ip inside network access in mongoDB atlas, i allow from everywhere too, but i keep getting the same error :(

The full error log when i start a server:

```
App 37683 output: (node:37683) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
App 37683 output:     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/xued8690/nodevenv/public_html/monthy-replay-back/14/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:824:32)
App 37683 output:     at /home/xued8690/nodevenv/public_html/monthy-replay-back/14/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:380:10
App 37683 output:     at /home/xued8690/nodevenv/public_html/monthy-replay-back/14/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
App 37683 output:     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
App 37683 output:     at promiseOrCallback (/home/xued8690/nodevenv/public_html/monthy-replay-back/14/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
App 37683 output:     at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/home/xued8690/nodevenv/public_html/monthy-replay-back/14/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1225:10)
App 37683 output:     at Mongoose.connect (/home/xued8690/nodevenv/public_html/monthy-replay-back/14/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:379:20)
App 37683 output:     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/xued8690/public_html/monthy-replay-back/app.js:33:10)
App 37683 output:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
App 37683 output:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
App 37683 output: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm able to add a catch after the function connect:

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@DATABASENAME/monthy-replay?retryWrites=true&w=majority`)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The error is:

> App 38402 output:   reason: TopologyDescription { App 38402 output:
> type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary', App 38402 output:     servers: Map(3) {
> App 38402 output:
> 'ac-htfw8mw-shard-00-02.xxxxx.mongodb.net:27017' =>
> [ServerDescription], App 38402 output:
> 'ac-htfw8mw-shard-00-00.xxxxx.mongodb.net:27017' =>
> [ServerDescription], App 38402 output:
> 'ac-htfw8mw-shard-00-01.xxxxx.mongodb.net:27017' =>
> [ServerDescription] App 38402 output:     }, App 38402 output:
> stale: false, App 38402 output:     compatible: true, App 38402
> output:     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000, App 38402 output:
> localThresholdMS: 15, App 38402 output:     setName:
> 'atlas-10px6i-shard-0', App 38402 output:
> logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined App 38402 output:   }, App
> 38402 output:   code: undefined App 38402 output: }

Comment: You need a detailed error message to understand what is going wrong. Or you can debug your code step-by-step to get to the point where everything goes wrong. Step-by-step debugging is easy using an IDE like Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i'm front developper so i'm new to that.
But, like i say in local everythin is fine. When i deploy the error com from findOne on the model (like he say in the link).

It's a mongoDB native function, i don't see what i can really do https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/

Ps: if is what you want say, i check before the variable email and everything is good.

Comment: @Robert I found a error and update my response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution !!!

The problem com from SSH thanks to this post https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/getting-econnrefused-and-replicasetnoprimary-errors/172477/3

You have to authorize the IP on the server and not mongoDB.
With Cpanel open the module Autorisation SSH, ir you have to add the ip and select the port 27017 (very important!), this will create a outgoing connection.

To be very clear, in my case i got the error follow (see on top who i got them):

```
App 38402 output: reason: TopologyDescription { 
 App 38402 output:
  type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary', App 38402 output: servers: Map(3) { 
   App 38402 output:
    'ac-htfw8mw-shard-00-02.xxxxx.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription], 
   App 38402 output:
    'ac-htfw8mw-shard-00-00.xxxxx.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
   App 38402 output:
    'ac-htfw8mw-shard-00-01.xxxxx.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription] App 
    38402 output: }, 
    App 38402 output:
     stale: false, App 38402 output: compatible: true, App 38402 output: 
     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000, App 38402 output:
     localThresholdMS: 15, App 38402 output: setName: 'atlas-10px6i-shard-0', App 
     38402 output:
  logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined App 38402 output: }, App 38402 output: 
 code: undefined App 38402 output: 
}
```

The ip you have to add is this `ac-htfw8mw-shard-00-02.xxxxx.mongodb.net` and select the port after the ip 27017.
And yes in my case i have to do that on the three ip.

```
ac-htfw8mw-shard-00-00.xxxxx.mongodb.net
ac-htfw8mw-shard-00-02.xxxxx.mongodb.net
ac-htfw8mw-shard-00-01.xxxxx.mongodb.net
```

Comment: Thanks you so much ! That was the problem. It works for me.